# Why does this code only work intermittently? Sometimes I get an error that I can't find on Google

Tags: python, oauth, cloud

I'm using the below code to connect to the Google BigQuery API. It only works intermittently. After this part, I attempt to send a dataframe to a BQ table via the "to_gbq" function. That part also only sometimes works, and other times fails due to the same error message.

Code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

path_to_json = 'gbq_key.json'
my_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(path_to_json)

my_project = 'myprojectnameishere'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=my_credentials, project=my_project)
print('connected')
```

**AttributeError: module 'google.api_core' has no attribute 'client_options'**

Detailed error:

```
  File "/home/my_user_name/get_mini_bq_helper.py", line 8, in <module>
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials=my_credentials, project=my_project)
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 226, in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py", line 321, in __init__
    Client.__init__(
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/client/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    client_options = google.api_core.client_options.ClientOptions()
AttributeError: module 'google.api_core' has no attribute 'client_options'
```

I am hosting this on PythonAnywhere but I randomly get this error locally as well. Sometimes it connects with no issue, but most of the time I get this error. Also, I couldn't find this error anywhere on Google/Stack Overflow. Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: have you tried to update modules ?

Comment: yeah. It's working now though, and I don't know why. Oh well, thank you.